# How to see unpublishes content types In a view?

Tags: 8, users

I have a view which displays a list of unpublished content type "Nascholingen".

I use D8 + varbase + content access module

In super admin all goes good. I added a new rol called "lid". Logged in with this member the view does not display any result.

I did 
- remove permissions on the view
- added all needed permissions on /permissions to edit this
- Access control for "Nascholingen" are set correctly.
- set priority of Content Access to 10
- Rebuild with drush cr

But whatever I do no results are displayed. grrr

Any suggestions? Is there a good way for debugging this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node');
  $query->condition('status', 0); // 0 CERO IS UNPUBLISHED
  $query->condition('type', 'CONTENT TYPE NAME');
  $entity_crop = $query->execute();

Comment: Not clear enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with the following module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/view_unpublished

After installation there are some new permissions in the permissions list which should be configurated and then unpublished items will be visible for the roles you configured.